# Sophos what is the current client definition?

Tags: anti-virus, sophos

I'm unfamiliar with Sophos Endpoint Security and have taken over a client who is using version 9.5. The Sophos server appears to be updating without issues, but the clients are unable to receive the new updates from the server.

I'd like to know when the clients last successfully received an update but the control panel just shows "Updating: failed" and the update log (alc.log) only gives one day of logs.

Anyone got any ideas about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to see when a client last updated:

- On a client, hover over the shield in the system tray and the tooltip should say when the client last updated.
- On a client, open the Sophos Application and on the left it should say when it was last updated.
- The Sophos Enterprise Console should also tell you if a client is up to date, or `Not Since <Time of last update>`.

To rectify the problem you can either try to redeploy the software from the Sophos Enterprise Console, or on the client run the installer from the Sophos network share. Sophos support would probably be the next best step, which IIRC is included with the product.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for responding. The client solutions both just said "Updating: Failed"
The Server console did show the proper date though - thanks for that!